# How to make Toggle Button with Animated.View in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, toggle, togglebutton

I can only use react native in the project, I need to make a Toggle Component with AnimatedView. I tried with react native switcher but it won't be responsive for mobile and web at the same time.

[image: here is the design for switcher that I need to implement]
Here is my code

```
export const ToggleButton = () => {
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const toggleSwitch = () => {
if (isEnabled) {
  setText('OFF');
} else {
  setText('ON');
}
setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
};
 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    {isEnabled ? <Text style={styles.textOn}>On</Text> : <Text style={styles.textOff}>Off</Text>}
    <Switch
      trackColor={{ false: Colors.BlueLight, true: Colors.PurpleLight }}
      thumbColor={isEnabled ? Colors.BlueLight : Colors.BlueLight}
      ios_backgroundColor="#3E3E3E"
      onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
      value={isEnabled}
    />
  </View>
</View>
);
};
```

Someone give me a recommendation how to do it?

Comment: can you share an expo snack for the same? 
also cant you use any external library?

Comment: No, only react-native

Comment: external packages are also built on react native only

Comment: yes, I can only use react-native

Comment: so you can use external packages?

Comment: Yes yes :) only packages from react-native

Comment: damnn, this is tough then

Comment: hey @Manche finally i did it,

Answer (score 6):

Hye finally i made a custom switch, do check out :

Do check out this expo https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/gnarly-sandwich

Its completely built with react native, no external libraries etc

[image]

Do lemme know in case of any doubts :)

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Easing
} from 'react-native';


export default function App() {

    const positionButton = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false);

  const startAnimToOff = () => {
    Animated.timing(positionButton,{
      toValue:0,
      duration:500,
      easing:Easing.ease
    }).start()
  };

  const startAnimToOn = () => {
 Animated.timing(positionButton,{
      toValue:1,
      duration:500,
      easing:Easing.ease
    }).start()

  };

  const positionInterPol = positionButton.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1],outputRange:[0,30]})

  const backgroundColorAnim = positionButton.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1],outputRange:["#767577","#81b0ff"]})

  const initialOpacityOn = positionButton.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1],outputRange:[0,1]})

    const initialOpacityOff = positionButton.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1],outputRange:[1,0]})

  const onPress = () => {
    if (isOn) {
      startAnimToOff();
      setIsOn(false);
    } else {
      startAnimToOn();
      setIsOn(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{height:30,width:60}}  activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={onPress} >
      <Animated.View style={[styles.mainStyes,{
        backgroundColor:backgroundColorAnim
      }]} >
        <Animated.Text
          style={[
            styles.eahcStyles,
            {
              opacity: initialOpacityOn,
            },
          ]}>
          ON
        </Animated.Text>
        <Animated.Text
          style={[
            styles.eahcStylesOf,
            {
              opacity: initialOpacityOff,
            },
          ]}>
          OFF
        </Animated.Text>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.basicStyle,{
          transform:[{
            translateX:positionInterPol
          }]
        }]} />
          </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  basicStyle: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    marginTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  eahcStyles: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#f5dd4b',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 6,
    left: 5,
  },

  eahcStylesOf: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#f4f3f4',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 6,
    right: 5,
  },
  mainStyes: {
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#81b0ff',
    height: 30,
    width: 60,
  },

  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```